# Azure DevOps Pipelines build using Xcode CLI command, xcodebuild, failing. Cannot open content.xcworkspacedata file

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild

I am attempting to trigger an Xcode build using Azure Pipelines. Pipelines essentially uses Xcode BuildTools commands to create the build. I am receiving the following error where I've inserted Project and ProjectPath to replace:

> xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project ProjectName.xcodeproj' from folder 'ProjectPath'. Reason: Could not open workspace file at ProjectPath.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata

Strange thing is that if I run my build command directly on the build server, from the build server's CLI, there is no issue and the build succeeds. However, when I try via Pipelines it says that this particular file, `contents.xcworkspacedata`, can't be opened.